# Dual slope ADC circuit

Tags: adc, calibration, compensation

I`m currently building a dual slope ADC with discrete components. As expected, some errors were observed. I have calculated both the gain error and offset error variables.

Now that I know these variables, how can I apply the required compensation and is it better to implement it in software or hardware?

[image]

Comment: What exactly have you determined are the root causes of the errors? Your circuit is not ideal in a number of ways, and I would expect significant linearity errors and temperature dependency.

Comment: The input voltage is not very accurate also the LM741 is quite a bad op-amp so it will be replace by a TL071.

Comment: Have you computed the ERROR of that 1MegOhm feedback resistor? Dual Slope ADCs use a nearly perfect Integrator. That 1Megohm ruins the integration.

Comment: Good for you. You don't need the 1M resistor, that will wreck your linearity. You might as well put offset and gain in a calibration step, then you can null out any front end you put on it. You do not need DC feedback across your integrator, lose the other resistor as well (keep the 10k). Your software controls the integrator output via the switches, pushing current into or pulling it out of the integrator input. When it crosses 0 V, your comparator flips so you can tell how long it took.

Comment: @Neil_UK Sorry to bother you again but wouldn`t removing the feedback resistor cause saturaion due to opamp offsets and bias currents and is it better to use the offset null pins provided by the opamp?

Comment: @aid846 You obviously haven't 'walked through' how this ADC works. With bias and offset currents, if you do nothing, then the amp will eventually saturate, so what? But you're not doing nothing. You're setting the integrator output to zero using the first two switches to ramp up a bit, then ramp down until the comparator flips, then you ramp up with your unknown input on switch 6/8/9 for a defined time, then you ramp down with your reference, recording the time when the comparator again flips. Repeat for another reading, or stop taking readings and let the amp saturate, it won't damage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-zero is a function that can be added in hardware or software, software is probably better but do a conversion cycle to measure the zero (assuming you have the ability to measure bipolar voltages). You could alternatively add a zero trim with a trimpot but it won't correct for drift.

If the reference is stable by not accurate you can calibrate it digitally or with something like a trimpot. A high-resolution fractional multiply could be a bit of a pain on a small micro or an utterly negligible computation on a more powerful CPU.

You should not need the 1M resistor, you drive the integrator actively up and down so you don't need to worry about it saturating.

Error sources include op-amp offset, reference error, linearity errors due to op-amp non-ideality, resistance variation of the analog switches, dielectric absorption of the integrating capacitor etc. Comparator speed can add some error but the LM311 is probably not a problem given your long integration time.

Errors in the integrating capacitor and resistor and clock frequency should cancel out.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly the integrator will not have enough time to saturate if we keep the charging time low enough?

Comment: The unknown voltage integration time is a certain number of clock cycles (which you choose), starting when it crosses 0V. You know the maximum input voltage, and what voltage the integrator saturates at, so pick R & C so that cannot happen unless the input voltage is too high.

Comment: So by picking R and C we are varying the the slope so as not to let the integrator saturate in the chosen amount of charging time?

Comment: Yes, for the maximum input voltage.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is this what were you tying to tell me; since we eliminate the dc feedback we would have the open loop gain of the opamp at DC but since capacitor voltage cannot change instantly we are using r and c in order to avoid saturation.

Comment: Your external control circuitry effectively acts as feedback to prevent saturation. This is fundamental to dual slope conversion.

Comment: Understood clearly since the first part of the dual slope (charging) is always a fixed count (time) variable slope  so you can limit this time in order to avoid saturation. Also is a reset switch required in parallel with the capacitor? Regarding the compensation my idea was to supply the dual slope with 2 stable voltages in order to calculate both the gain and offset error. After that I can compensate for this gain error by mutliplying the final conversion by its reciprocal but I do not know if this is the norm of doing things.Moreover is I dont know how to compensate for the offset error.

Comment: No, a switch is not required, the comparator output has all the information required. You can measure the voltage with input shorted to ground and then subtract that number (could be of either polarity) digitally from the unknown reading, which will correct for offset. Gain is similar, subtract the offset first then scale. Is it "normal"? 3-1/2 digit conversion chips use auto-zero, as I mentioned so no offset correction and the circuit is accurate enough that the full scale reading closely matches the reference and rollover error is minimal.

Comment: If in the future I would want to automate this process (self-calibration) how could I go about this but still using the above circuitry?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but wouldnt removing the feedback resistor cause saturaion due to opamp offsets and bias currents?

Comment: Is it better to use the offsetnull pins provided by the opamp?